# find an element inside an sibling of another element with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" value="play" class="btnplay"></input>
    <audio class="song">
        <source src="<%# Eval("f_audio") %>" />
    </audio>
    <div class="progress-show">
        <span class=".currTime">dsgbadgnsetb</span>
        <input class="progress-slider mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" tabindex="0">
        <span class=".totalTime">sfhsg s</span>
        <input class="volume-slider mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" tabindex="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find the span tag with the class of currTime and change it's value but through the btnplay like this:

```js
$('.btnplay').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.progress-show').next('.currTime').text('111111');
});
```

but it doesn't work, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: I used a repeater so there are many divs with the same classes so I can not easily use $('.currTime'), I need to find it inside this context

Comment: Is that normal that your `<input>` fields aren't closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML and rename CSS class as `currTime` instead of `.currTime` otherwise you need to escape `.` as its a metacharacter

HTML change

```
<span class="currTime">dsgbadgnsetb</span>
```

Then use, `children()` should be used to get child element.

```
$('.btnplay').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.progress-show').children('.currTime').text('111111');
});
```

---

Using existing HTML, Escape meta-character `.` using `\\`

```
$('.btnplay').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.progress-show').children('.\\.currTime').text('111111');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a stupid mistake and used .currTime as a class name :D

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find()` instead of `.next()` as `.currTime` is child element and not next sibling of `.progress-show`:

```
$('.btnplay').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.progress-show').find('.currTime').text('111111');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` will fetch you `<audio>` element. You must try finding the element like:

```
jQuery(".btnplay").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).siblings(".progress-show").find(".currTime").text("Some Text");
});
```

Documentation for [jQuery.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [jQuery.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)